# PL/SQL : returned sys_refcursor from a function / Replacing dynamically request by another

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

my function is this one :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION replaceRequest(mysql IN varchar2)
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
opt SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
open opt for select * from rteuti;
return opt;
END replaceRequest;
/
```

And here my call :

```
select replaceRequest('foo') from dual;
```

I had hope this request will return me the result of:

```
select * from rteuti
```

Its indeed not the real case, but this simple case is enough to point my problem. I wanna replace a query by another without knowing the number of columns ( number of columns is a parameter in the real function and i manage to generate the query i wanted).

In my actual Oracle PLSQL knowledge, SYS_REFCURSOR is the only way to return something that looks like a query result (without knowing the number of column in advance).

But in action, it fails with ERROR in my Squirrel Client, or via Java JDBC. I got only one line with one columns with "error"

In PgPL/SQL it is possible to do that. I'm surprse i cant do it with oracle.

PS : With some more research i found that SYS_REFCURSOR is a pointer on a ResultSET and not a resultset. Is there any way to return the result set or modify my select to have a result set ?

Comment: what is the higher-level task you're trying to solve doing this?

Comment: A library i cant modify is doing some request like : select foo from footable group by foo to get all distinct value in this table and i takes many seconds, i know that if do many request to get value one at a time it's much much better, like millisecons, so i try to recompose a dataset with one or few queries and return it as one result. I manage to build a one unique request by requesting many time in my function and building a union request of all previous request. It's indeed strange because i do me request twice but its far quicker than the original request.

Comment: With PGPL/SQL (Postgres), Pipelined data is supporting unkwoned number of columns so it's much easier to achieve. In PGPL/SQL the structure of columns must be described in the request like select * from magicfunction(arguments) as f(a varchar,b varchar, c timestamp)

Comment: So, what is the exact error message returned?

Comment: SYS_REFCCURSOR is not a standard JDBC feature, it's an extension to JDBC, see documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraint.htm#i1058743, there is an example how to deal with refcursor (you must retrieve the ref_cursor using OracleTypes.CURSOR type and cast it to jdbc.ResultSet - see example)